# How to merge row which are not present in other table in sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like
**CL_Client**
cl_id | cl_name |cl_system
1     |    a    |Dpo
2     |    b    | Dpo
3     |    c    |Dpo
4     |    d
**CLOI_ClientOrderItems**

```
Cl_id|cl_name|orderid|    date      |status |masterid
  1  |   a   | 123   |  27/5/0215   |  12   |  111
  1  |   a   | 123   |  27/5/0215   |  15   |  111
  2  |   b   | 213   |  27/5/0215   |  12   |  222
  3  |   c   | 452   |  27/5/0215   |  16   |  333
  4  |   d   | 458   |  27/5/0215   |  20   |  444
  4  |   d   | 452   |  27/5/0215   |  22   |  333
```

**Invoice table**

```
orderid|rate|master id|invoice_date
  123  |10  | 111     |27/5/2015
  213  |10  | 222     |27/5/2015
  458  |10  | 444     |27/5/2015
```

in invoice table there is no row of masterorderid 333 but in result I want to show that also.

I have tried this query but it's not working correctly:

```
SELECT distinct 
    C.cl_id,
    C.cl_name,
    [dbo].getOrderCountbyMasterorderID(CO.masterorderid) as No_Of_Orders,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CO.cloi_order_date,108) as OrderTime,
    I.in_total,
    CO.MasterOrderId,
    CO.cloi_current_status
from
    dbo.CL_Clients C
    INNER JOIN dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems CO
        ON C.cl_id = CO.cl_id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IN_Invoices I
        ON CO.MasterOrderId = I.MasterOrderId
where
    CO.cloi_current_status in(7,8,160,163,167,170,250,251,162) and
    C.cl_system='Dpo' and
    datepart(yyyy,I.in_date_issued)=2015 and
    datepart(mm,I.in_date_issued)=05 and
    datepart(dd,I.in_date_issued)=27
group by
    C.cl_id,
    C.cl_name,
    CO.masterorderid,
    CO.cloi_order_date,
    CO.cloi_current_status,
    I.in_total,
    CO.MasterOrderId 
order by 
    OrderTime
```

**expected result**

```
cl_id | cl_name |No_Of_Orders|  OrderTime|in_total|MasterOrderId|status
1     |    a    |2       |  09:45    | 65.33  |111          |12       
2     |    b    |1       |  09:53    | 65.33  |222          |15   
3     |    c    |1       |  09:54    | 43.21  |333          |16
4     |    d    |2       |  09:56    | 43.21  |444          |20
```

Comment: Using datepart (or other functions) in search criteria can result in a really bad performance because indexes cannot be used. You should really do this by using I.in_date_issued >= '20150527' and I.in_date_issued < '20150528.'

Comment: ols can you give me the query because i tried lot but i am not getting the row which are not present in invoice table

Comment: If getOrderCountbyMasterorderID is a scalar UDF that fetches rows from a table, you should really also consider replacing it with either inline function or just adding the logic in this fetch. UDFs slow down queries a lot.

Comment: Also, your `where` clause is effectively changing the `left join` to an `inner join`, since it's involving data from your right table (in this case, `IN_Invoices`).

Comment: ya even i did left join but result not getting

Comment: show data for `CL_Clients` table

Comment: What about data in column `cl_system` from table `CL_Clients`

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown data for `CL_Clients` table.

Try executing this query first

```
SELECT distinct 
    C.cl_id,
    C.cl_name,
    [dbo].getOrderCountbyMasterorderID(CO.masterorderid) as No_Of_Orders,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CO.cloi_order_date,108) as OrderTime,
    --I.in_total,
    CO.MasterOrderId,
    CO.cloi_current_status
from
    dbo.CL_Clients C
    INNER JOIN dbo.CLOI_ClientOrderItems CO
        ON C.cl_id = CO.cl_id 
    --LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IN_Invoices I
        --ON CO.MasterOrderId = I.MasterOrderId
where
    CO.cloi_current_status in(7,8,160,163,167,170,250,251,162)
     and C.cl_system='Dpo'
     --and datepart(yyyy,I.in_date_issued)=2015
     --and datepart(mm,I.in_date_issued)=05
     --and datepart(dd,I.in_date_issued)=27
group by
    C.cl_id,
    C.cl_name,
    CO.masterorderid,
    CO.cloi_order_date,
    CO.cloi_current_status,
    --I.in_total,
    CO.MasterOrderId 
order by 
    OrderTime
```

If `masterorderid = 333` is not even displayed here, then check your where clauses.

Comment: same result...here i am getting masteroderid getting duplicate so how to get only single masterorderid

Comment: any one can help this query?